# Degeneracy in circumcircle radius for Delaunay triangulation in Python

Tags: python, delaunay

So I'm trying to construct a Delaunay triangulation in Python. Here's my current code:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from functools import cache
from typing import NamedTuple


@cache
def circumcircle(triangle: DelaunayTriangle) -> tuple[Point, int]:
    # Store the variables which are needed for this calculation
    ax, ay = triangle.a
    bx, by = triangle.b
    cx, cy = triangle.c
    aax, aay = triangle.a * triangle.a
    bbx, bby = triangle.b * triangle.b
    ccx, ccy = triangle.c * triangle.c

    # Calculate the circumradius
    d = 2 * (ax * (by - cy) + bx * (cy - ay) + cx * (ay - by))

    # Calculate the circumcenter
    ux = (aax + aay) * (by - cy) + (bbx + bby) * (cy - ay) + (ccx + ccy) * (ay - by)
    uy = (aax + aay) * (cx - bx) + (bbx + bby) * (ax - cx) + (ccx + ccy) * (bx - ax)

    # Return the values
    return Point(int(ux / d), int(uy / d)), d


@cache
def is_shared_edge(edge_one: GraphEdge, edge_two: GraphEdge) -> bool:
    return (
        edge_one.source == edge_two.source
        and edge_one.destination == edge_two.destination
    ) or (
        edge_one.source == edge_two.destination
        and edge_one.destination == edge_two.source
    )


class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<Point (X={self.x}) (Y={self.y})>"

    def __mul__(self, other: object) -> Point:
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            return Point(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)
        raise NotImplementedError

    def distance_to(self, point: Point) -> int:
        return int(abs(math.hypot(point.x - self.x, point.y - self.y)))


class GraphEdge(NamedTuple):
    source: Point
    destination: Point
    distance: int


class DelaunayTriangle:
    def __init__(self, a: Point, b: Point, c: Point) -> None:
        self.a: Point = a
        self.b: Point = b
        self.c: Point = c
        self.edges: list[GraphEdge] = [
            GraphEdge(a, b, a.distance_to(b)),
            GraphEdge(b, c, b.distance_to(c)),
            GraphEdge(a, c, a.distance_to(c)),
        ]
        circumcenter, circumradius = circumcircle(self)
        self.circumcenter: Point = circumcenter
        self.circumradius: float = circumradius

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<DelaunayTriangle (A={self.a}) (B={self.b}) (C={self.c})>"

    def has_point(self, point: Point) -> bool:
        return self.a == point or self.b == point or self.c == point


class DelaunayGraph:
    def __init__(self, grid_width: int, grid_height: int, super_offset: int) -> None:
        self.super_point_a: Point = Point(-super_offset, -super_offset)
        self.super_point_b: Point = Point(2 * grid_width + super_offset, -super_offset)
        self.super_point_c: Point = Point(-super_offset, 2 * grid_height + super_offset)
        self.triangulation: list[DelaunayTriangle] = [
            DelaunayTriangle(self.super_point_a, self.super_point_b, self.super_point_c)
        ]

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<DelaunayGraph (Triangle count={len(self.triangulation)})>"

    @staticmethod
    def is_point_in_circumcircle(triangle: DelaunayTriangle, point: Point) -> bool:
        return triangle.circumradius > point.distance_to(triangle.circumcenter)

    def add_point(self, point: Point) -> None:
        # Find all the triangles whose circumcircle contains the new point
        bad_triangles = [
            triangle
            for triangle in self.triangulation
            if self.is_point_in_circumcircle(triangle, point)
        ]

        # Find the convex hull (boundary that contains every point)
        polygon = []
        for triangle in bad_triangles:
            for edge in triangle.edges:
                is_shared = False
                for other_triangle in bad_triangles:
                    if triangle == other_triangle:
                        continue

                    for other_triangle_edge in other_triangle.edges:
                        if is_shared_edge(edge, other_triangle_edge):
                            is_shared = True

                if not is_shared:
                    polygon.append(edge)

        # Delete the bad triangles
        for triangle in bad_triangles:
            self.triangulation.remove(triangle)

        # Create a new triangle for each new edge
        for new_edge in polygon:
            self.triangulation.append(
                DelaunayTriangle(new_edge.source, new_edge.destination, point)
            )

    def export(self) -> list[GraphEdge]:
        final = []
        for triangle in self.triangulation:
            if (
                triangle.has_point(self.super_point_a)
                or triangle.has_point(self.super_point_b)
                or triangle.has_point(self.super_point_c)
            ):
                continue
            else:
                for edge in triangle.edges:
                    final.append(edge)

        return final
```

However, when I run it, sometimes I get degenerative points (where the circumradius is 0). This breaks the program as you can't have a zero radius for a circle in a Delaunay triangulation. So is there any way to fix this degeneracy?

Also how could I optimise the add_point() function removing a couple of those nested for loops?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the code that will run it and produce the `ZeroDivisionError`:

```py
rooms = [Point(32, 16), Point(32, 8), Point(32, 2), Point(25, 20), Point(24, 12), Point(24, 3), Point(14, 19), Point(14, 10), Point(16, 1), Point(9, 1), Point(3, 17), Point(3, 9), Point(1, 2)]
delaunay_graph = DelaunayGraph(36, 24, -100)
for room in rooms:
    delaunay_graph.add_point(room)
```

EDIT 2: So after a bit more testing, it seems like sorting the points solves the problem:

```py
rooms = [Point(32, 16), Point(32, 8), Point(32, 2), Point(25, 20), Point(24, 12), Point(24, 3), Point(14, 19), Point(14, 10), Point(16, 1), Point(9, 1), Point(3, 17), Point(3, 9), Point(1, 2)]
delaunay_graph = DelaunayGraph(36, 24, -100)
for room in sorted(rooms, key=lambda x: x):
    delaunay_graph.add_point(room)
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: What is NamedTuple. There is a namedtuple in collections, but has different case

Comment: Its from the typing library, makes for a more readable look.

Comment: You should include data that causes the problem

Comment: X and y are indexes in a 2D array. I've added some code that will run it and produce an error.

Comment: I think the problem occurs if any 3 of the points added have the same x or y axis.

Comment: Might not be related to your problem, but it's suspicious to me that you're rounding coordinates and distance values towards zero. Are you certain about that decision?

Comment: The center of a circumcenter that passes for 3 collinear points is infinite, so it is correct that it gives division by zero

Comment: Maybe it should return an object representing the infinite

Comment: @DanGetz my Point named tuple was meant for use in a 2D grid so all of the values would be int. It would be better as floats tho.

Comment: Being an int doesn't imply rounding towards zero; there are other ways of rounding.

Comment: @Colim, however, sometimes even with 3 points with the same axis, no errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this code, you need to deal with infinity. You will need to check all your code to include infinity (or a very large integer)

try using math.inf

```
@cache
def circumcircle(triangle: DelaunayTriangle) -> tuple[Point, int]:
    ...
    # Return the values
    try:
        return Point(int(ux / d), int(uy / d)), d
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return Point(math.inf,math.inf), d


class Point(NamedTuple):
    ...
    def distance_to(self, point: Point) -> int:
        try:
            return int(abs(math.hypot(point.x - self.x, point.y - self.y)))
        except OverflowError:
            return math.inf
```

If you work with [Homogeneneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), it would naturally deal with infinites

Comment: So would this fix the problem of having 3 collinear points?

Comment: You need to check the entire code, and consider what happens with an infinite coordinate. If you worked with Homogenenous Coordinates, a lot of your geometrical logic would behave the same with points on the infinite. Homogenenous coordinates add another dimension, which naturally represent infinite, and deals with common geometric constructions like intersections

Answer (score 0):

If you work with geographic applications at all, you will run into cases where the x,y coordinates have a large magnitude even though the difference between neighboring points may be small.  In such a case, you'll experience loss of precision for terms such as aax, aay = triangle.a * triangle.a.  The product could become so large that it washes out low-order digits that are actually relevant to your calculation. You might want to look at [The Wikipedia article on catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation)

Computational geometry problems are notorious for overflow and precision issues. Jonathan Shewchuk worked out algorithms for adaptive-precision computations specifically for the Delauany. They are devilishly complicated, but brilliant, and worth a look just to appreciate the problem   You can also find helpful information at [Fast Robust Predicates for Computational Geometry](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/robust.html#:%7E:text=The%20incircle%20test%20determines%20whether,the%20coordinates%20of%20the%20points.)  You should take a look at the InCircle determinant they show on that page since it will work very well for you.

I have some Java code that computes circumcircles.  It is intended to avoid overflow issues such as I described above.  Perhaps you can adapt it to Python.

```
public void compute(
final double x0,
final double y0,
final double x1,
final double y1,
final double x2,
final double y2) {

double bx, by, cx, cy, d, c2, b2;

// to reduce loss-of-precision, 
// map every thing some one of the vertices is at the origin
bx = x1 - x0;
by = y1 - y0;
cx = x2 - x0;
cy = y2 - y0;

d = 2 * (bx * cy - by * cx);
if (Math.abs(d) < MIN_TRIG_AREA) {  // min trig area is arbitrary, 1.0e-16
  // the triangle is close to the degenerate case
  // (all 3 points in a straight line)
  // even if determinant d is not zero, numeric precision
  // issues might lead to a very poor computation for
  // the circumcircle.
  this.centerX = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  this.centerY = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  r2 = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  return;
}
b2 = bx * bx + by * by;
c2 = cx * cx + cy * cy;

// Populate the member elements
this.centerX = (cy * b2 - by * c2) / d;
this.centerY = (bx * c2 - cx * b2) / d;
this.radiusSquared = this.centerX * this.centerX + this.centerY * this.centerY;
this.centerX += x0;
this.centerY += y0;
```

Finally, I wrote a document describing algorithms I used in my own Delaunay implementation.  I make no claim to being an authority, so read it with a healthy skepticism....  Perhaps you can lift some ideas from it.  See [Tinfour Algorithms and Data Elements](https://gwlucastrig.github.io/TinfourDocs/TinfourAlgorithmsAndDataElements.pdf)